Using two network / roads vector layers to calculate paths / routes
I'm working on a new problem that is complex to me, although I'd not be surprise to discover that there is already a solution to it in qgis.
Here's an illustration of my problem :

I have two roads vector layers in qgis.

Green layer : Roads, comes from an official source
Red layer : Private water company network, private data

Generally speaking, the water network follows roads. Not exactly, there also are holes in the shapefile.
What I would like to do is to be able to generate paths between two points (purple on the image)
If I generate a path using only my network layer, it will use the layer and draw a straight line between the end of my network layer and the point.
However, I'd like to find a way to use the existing green roads layer as the first thing to use if there's no red network available.
Expected behavior : If there's no direct red path or if there are holes in the red path between point A and B, see if you can use green roads to get any closer and go from there (blue)
Is there any way to achieve this ?

As per the [help/behavior] please don’t include chitchat like thanks, signature, etc in your posts.

I'm not aware of any tools that swaps from one network dataset to another when a destination cannot be reached. I think you need to merge both datasets into a single network dataset. If red genuinely does not connect through to "B" but green does, a shortest path search will find that route.
